# Open Google Form every Thursday

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to figure out how to check if it the current time is Thursday 9:00 AM.  I don't care about date in any other way except that it is a Thursday and that it is past 9:00 AM.

I've never written a single google script before and the API here doesn't seem to offer something like what I am looking for: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/date-field

Here is how far I've gotten:

```
FORM_OPEN_DATE   =  "2016-03-09 12:20";
FORM_CLOSE_DATE  =  "2016-03-09 12:30";

function Initialize() {
  if ((FORM_OPEN_DATE !== "") && 
      ((new Date()).getTime() < parseDate_(FORM_OPEN_DATE).getTime())) { 
    closeForm();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("openForm")
    .timeBased()
    .at(parseDate_(FORM_OPEN_DATE))
    .create();
  }   

  if (FORM_CLOSE_DATE !== "") { 
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("closeForm")
    .timeBased()
    .at(parseDate_(FORM_CLOSE_DATE))
    .create(); 
  }
}
```

My script above works as intended, it will open and close the form between the time frames, however I am trying to figure out how to check based on the day of the week as oppose to exact date.  Reason being is that I  wish for the form to open itself every thursday at 9:00 AM and close at 8:30 PM.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript method `getDay()` returns the day of the week as a number.  Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on.  So, Thursday would be 4.

```
if (new Date().getDay() === 4) {//true block};
```

Comment: Thanks for that Sandy, are you certain that it is day of the week?  According to the documentation its the day of the month:

`getDay() Integer Gets the day of the month for this date.`
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/date-field

Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually now that I read your comment better you said `javascript method getDay()` I am referring to google script `getDay()`  How would I implement javascript into google script?

Comment: Apps Script uses JavaScript for the server side language.  Most JavaScript functions are available in the google script, except for things that would affect HTML in a browser, which you obviously can't do directly from the server.  So, `getDay()` is available in the Apps Script JavaScript.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: ok but if you look at the link I gave you, that one says day of the month, is your function different somehow?  I must be missing something.  I tested your theory and it gave me back a 4.  So you are correct, I am just confused why is it a 4 and 10 as today is the 10th of the month.

Comment: The name of the getDay() method is not as descriptive as it could be. The name could imply different things. There is a getDate() method, that gets the day of the month. The getDate() method also doesn't have a great name. But, that's just the way it is. [Date methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)